# MySQL insert with mbox format

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe it's my query, but I don't think so. I'm attempting to import messages parsed from an mbox format into MySQL, but MySQL fails when I do it through PHP or manually through phpMyAdmin. Any thoughts?

```
$sql='INSERT INTO `listserv_mbox` ("message-id", "mbox") 
   VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($structure->headers['message-id']).'"
           ,"'.mysql_real_escape_string($message_base64).'")';

// Run our MySQL query
$db->Execute($sql);
```

This code looks correct to me, so I'm totally lost on why I cannot import this data for whatever reason. The error I keep getting is:

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"message-id", "mbox") VALUES ("<012c01c69c88$98e38250$31780b4b@dtadavid>","RnJvb' at line 1

The query looks like this. I couldn't get it to work before, so I decided to try base64_encode() on the message itself, but still it doesn't work. Here's the base64_encod()'d query.

```
INSERT INTO `listserv_mbox` ("message-id", "mbox") 
VALUES ("<012c01c69c88$98e38250$31780b4b@dtadavid>"
 ,"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")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `listserv_mbox` ("message-id", "mbox"
```

That should be

```
INSERT INTO `listserv_mbox` (`message-id`, `mbox`
```

`` ` `` instead of  `"`

Comment: Wow, I feel totally lame right now after staring at this for an hour. I seriously appreciate the quick response. That worked great. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe value is just too long for type of field "message_id"